# What's different between a single precision and double precision floating values?

Tags: java, c, types, floating-point, programming-languages

What's the difference between a single precision and double precision floating values?

Comment: Did you try some search first?

Comment: err...  the precision.  More specifically approximately 6 significant decimal digits vs 15 for single and double precision respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, `double` has at least as much precision as, and usually more than, `float`, and has at least the exponent range of, and usually more than, `float`.

The C standard only requires that `double` be able to represent all the values of `float`: “The set of values of the type `float` is a subset of the set of values of the type `double`…” (C 3028 6.2.5 10).

In typical common implementations today, `float` is represented with 32 bits in the [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) *binary32* format, and `double` is represented with 64 bits in the *binary64* format.

Answer (score 0):

Single precision (float) is stored in 4 bytes (32bits).
Double precision (double) is stored in 8 bytes (64bits).